# SQL not a single-group group function calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, ora-00937

```
Select CATEGORY, TITLE, RETAIL
From BOOKS
Where RETAIL = ( SELECT RETAIL-max(COST) From Books)
ORDER BY Category ASC;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show the retail prices which are less than the MAX cost of all the books

Example

```
MAX COST = $44
Display number of retail items that are LESS than $44
```

Comment: `Select CATEGORY, TITLE, RETAIL
From BOOKS
Where RETAIL < (SELECT MAX(COST) From Books)
ORDER BY Category ASC;`

Comment: MySQL returnin Oracle error codes? Sure you have the correct tags?

Comment: @FelixPamittan - that's an answer, not a comment. It also happens to be the best answer offered so far. You may want to consider changing it from a comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_BOOKS_PRICE
(
BOOK VARCHAR(24),
PRICE MONEY
)
GO

INSERT INTO TBL_BOOKS_PRICE
VALUES('BOOK1',33.00)
GO

INSERT INTO TBL_BOOKS_PRICE
VALUES('BOOK1',44.00)
GO

INSERT INTO TBL_BOOKS_PRICE
VALUES('BOOK1',43.00)
GO

INSERT INTO TBL_BOOKS_PRICE
VALUES('BOOK1',38.00)
GO

SELECT BOOK,PRICE FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRICE DESC) ID,* FROM TBL_BOOKS_PRICE
) A
WHERE ID<>1;
```

Comment: `GO` is an invalid statement in Oracle (or standard SQL) you might want to replace that with the proper statement terminator: `;` to make this valid SQL

Comment: `MONEY` is not an Oracle datatype. Aside from that - your query is inefficient; it orders all rows in the subquery, when only the max is needed. Finding the max of a set is far less work than ordering the whole set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
with tmp as (
select category, title, retail, max(cost) as retail_max_cost
from books group by category, title, retail)

select category, title, retail from tmp
where retail < retail_max_cost order by category;
```